# Building dynamic filter based on object function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am building a dynamic filter, something like [Yahoo Screener](https://finance.yahoo.com/screener/new). Here is how I have defined interface for the fields which are available:

```
export interface FilterField {
    label: string;
    selected: boolean;
    deletable: boolean;
    required?: boolean;
    lastValue?: any;
    viewSync?: boolean;
    inclusion?: 'include' | 'exclude';
    precision?: 'before' | 'after' | 'exact';
    controlType?: 'multiselect' | 'time' | 'tag';
    items?: Array<unknown>;
    f?: Function;
}
```

And the array of these filters looks like this:

```
public fields: Array<FilterField> = [
        {
            label: 'period',
            viewSync: true,
            selected: true,
            deletable: false,
            lastValue: null,
            required: true,
            f: (data: SomeObject) => {
                // here comes the filtering function
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'dayOfWeek',
            inclusion: 'include',
            selected: true,
            deletable: true,
            lastValue: [1,2],
            f: (data: SomeObject) => {
                // here comes the filtering function
            }
        },
        {
            label: 'startHour',
            precision: 'after',
            selected: true,
            deletable: true,
            lastValue: '12:00',
            controlType: 'time',
            f: (data: SomeObject) => {
                // here comes the filtering function
            }
        }, [...]
```

When the fields are selected I need to filter data based on those fields, their `lastValue` and other properties, like `inclusion` or `precision`. My idea was to set that `f: Function` to the callback which will be used to filter the data. The data itself is an object array, and some of those callbacks need to include a pretty specific logic.

How do I define such a function and how do I read properties of that particular field when executing the callback? Like for the dayOfWeek, I need to know if it should be included or excluded – and which days are set by the user. Something like this came to mind, but it is definitely not enough:

```
            label: 'dayOfWeek',
            inclusion: 'include',
            selected: true,
            deletable: true,
            lastValue: [1,2],
            f: (data: SomeObject) => {
                return inclusionPropertyOfThisObject == 'include'
                ? lastValuesOfThisParticularObject.includes(moment(data.date).startOf('day').day())
                : !lastValuesOfThisParticularObject.includes(moment(data.date).startOf('day').day())
            }
```

How do I implement the idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you typed the filter function to accept both the data and the filter field? Something like:

```js
export interface FilterField<T> {
    label: string;
    selected: boolean;
    deletable: boolean;
    required?: boolean;
    lastValue?: any;
    viewSync?: boolean;
    inclusion?: 'include' | 'exclude';
    precision?: 'before' | 'after' | 'exact';
    controlType?: 'multiselect' | 'time' | 'tag';
    items?: Array<T>;
    f?: (data: T, field: FilterField<T>) => boolean;
}
```

You'd have to make some adjustments to how `f` is called but this would allow you to access the fields and the data at the same time. Using your example:

```js
f: (data: SomeObject, field: FilterField<SomeObject>) => {
    return field.inclusion == 'include'
    ? field.lastValues.includes(moment(data.date).startOf('day').day())
    : !field.lastValues.includes(moment(data.date).startOf('day').day())
}
```

Comment: This seems to be very close to what I am looking for. How would I then chain the filters? Let's say I have a `const selectedFilters: Array<FilterField>` and a `let filteredData: Array<SomeObject> = []`.

Comment: Got it! `for ( const filter of selectedFilters ) {
   filteredData = filteredData.filter(s => filter.f.call(this, s, filter));
  }`